# Eclipse internal browser error when running a servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I use Eclipse EE Juno running on Ubuntu 12.04 in order to test simple servlet. Therefore I installed a web kit using following command in Eclipse

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

When I'm running the servlet internal browser shows html tags that I used in my servlet. like this (This problem not happens in Firefox)

```
<h3>Hello from servlet!!!</h3>
```

Here is the code of servlet

```
package org.javaweb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class SimpleServlet
*/
@WebServlet("/SimpleServlet")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
    printWriter.println("<h3>Hello from servlet!!!</h3>");
}

}
```

Where is the error ??
How to correct this??

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to mention the correct response type as text/html. As in, add this to your existing code and it should work fine for you:

```
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Firefox or web browsers in general are intelligent enough to guess if it's HTML content and render it correctly compared to Eclipse's internal browser.

Comment: yeh.. you are great. It solved the problem. If you can please explain me, when I'm running this on Windows7 I do not need to mention response type and internal browser worked normally. Why I should need to do that for Ubuntu?

Comment: It must be due the difference in the default web browsers in Eclipse for Windows and Ubuntu OS respectively. You can check what your default browser settings are by going to Eclipse->preferences->General->Network Connection->Web browser, and see whats set to default on Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Try to set content-type to HTML.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

I'm guessing eclipse built-in browser isn't always waiting for html content while firefox or any other common browser always fill content-type if not given.

Comment: If you can please explain me, when I'm running this on Windows7 I do not need to mention response type and internal browser worked normally. Why I should need to do that for Ubuntu?

Comment: Eclipse is using SWT. SWT browser uses different renderers depending on which OS you are. I'm not sure how eclipse is done on that side but default SWT renderer are IE for Windows, and WebKitGTK/Mozilla for Linux. As you're on ubuntu 12, WebKitGTK should be already installed and that's what SWT browser is using as default (Mozilla is a fallback option only). There should be an option somewhere in eclipse to change back to Mozilla (which should work as requested without setting content-type).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and descriptive explanation it helped me a lot.